# Compute perpendicular vector to a known vector, both embedded in the same plane, in 3D (R^3)

Tags: computational-geometry, numerical-methods

it seems to me that this is kind of a very easy question, but today I don't seem to find a reasonable answer by myself.
I have two points, A and B in R^3 (3D) that belong to plane PI.
I want to find a vector r in PI, perpendicular to the vector v = A - B. 
I know vector n, the normal of plane PI. Mathematically I can solve v.r = 0 and v x r = n, but the solution of this system in terms of r involves some divisions that I suspect could bring some numerical instabilities.
Can you suggest me any numerical/computationally good solution for this problem?

Thanks in advance,

Federico

Comment: "two points that belong to the same plane" interesting start

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Why not just compute the cross product V x N ?

Since the solution is in Pi, it is perpendicular to N, and V, so... ?

Comment: Thanks a lot!!! that was the kind of simple answer I just needed since today I couldn't see it by myself.

Comment: you should mention that V x N and N x V are different vectors, they are collinear but opposite.